# How to change track to oval track Turtle Racing game python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

So I need to make the turtles move in an oval track with lanes instead of across dotted lines that are vertical for each turtle however I am unable to find working methods of doing this online code I have used so far is as follows

```
from turtle import* 
from random import randint

speed(0)
penup()
goto(-200,200)
step=0
for step in range(20):
    write(step)
    right(90)
    forward(10)
    pendown()
    forward(130)
    penup()
    backward(140)
    left(90)
    forward(25)
```

Comment: Related answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465666/how-do-you-draw-an-ellipse-oval-in-turtle-graphics-python

Comment: does not work in the code i have the only one that did was just a white circle