# Python Turtle Vertical Oval

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, ellipse

I am playing around with Python's `turtle` module.

I want to draw a vertical oval, half of which is crossed by the y axis, when the user enters only the radius of a small arc (you can try 120).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4oCa.jpg) is an approximate diagram of what it should look like.

Here is the code snippet of how I usually draw an ellipse (you can draw a large arc first, then a small one).:

```
import turtle

r=int(input())  # smaller radius
t=turtle.Turtle()
for i in range(2):
    t.circle(r, 90)
    t.circle(r*2, 90)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Before the loop, do `t.seth(-45)` to set the orientation.

Comment: need half of the oval to intersect the y axis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you draw an ellipse/oval in turtle graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465666/how-do-you-draw-an-ellipse-oval-in-turtle-graphics)

Comment: No, only the radius of the small arc is known, and there the oval is drawn without interruption with the center coordinate

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
import turtle

r = 120

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.penup()
t.goto(r - r / 1.5, 0)
t.pendown()

t.left(45)
for i in range(2):
    t.circle(r, 90)
    t.circle(r / 2, 90)
```

I modified your original code so that there's a horizontal offset that centers the oval to x = 0. It also rotates the turtle before drawing, so that the oval gets rotated by the same amount. It doesn't use any extra libraries either.

Comment: Your `t.goto(r - r / 1.5, 0)` is a good approximation but places the image slightly left of center.  Instead try `t.setx(r * 2**0.5/4)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using your oringinal ellipse algorithm, plus the angle fix of @Corralien (+1).  It's overly complicated code as it draws the y-axis at the same time and centers the ellipse on the window:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

small_radius = int(input())
small_radius_versine = small_radius * (1 - 2**0.5/2)
small_radius_chord_length = small_radius * 2**0.5

large_radius = 2 * small_radius
large_radius_chord_length = large_radius * 2**0.5

distance_to_center = large_radius_chord_length/2 + small_radius_versine

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-small_radius_chord_length/2, small_radius_versine - distance_to_center)
turtle.pendown()

turtle.setheading(-45)

for _ in range(2):
    turtle.circle(small_radius, 45)

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(distance_to_center)
    turtle.backward(distance_to_center)
    turtle.right(90)

    turtle.circle(small_radius, 45)
    turtle.circle(large_radius, 90)

turtle.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]